# How to automate the collection of Defender performance data?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, windows-defender

Our IT department requested to collect ETW data from Defender during MSBuild-driven builds. We have intermittent build failures that are evidently caused by Defender (well, its user mode service) sitting on files with exclusive access. The issue is elusive, a classical Heisenbug. And despite attempts to reproduce this while recording ETW data, I haven't had luck reproducing it after two dozen or so tries.

The instructions state to use `New-MpPerformanceRecording -RecordTo <recording.etl>` followed by `Get-MpPerformanceReport -Path <recording.etl> ...`. The respective documentation from Microsoft can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/tune-performance-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide).

Now my main gripe with the process is that `New-MpPerformanceRecording` requires to:

> 3. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to stop and save recording, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel recording.

That means I cannot script the performance recordings along with the builds and always need to attend them. It's wasting a lot of time I don't really have to keep coming back to a window to look whether or not already to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

**Question:** How can I automate the process end-to-end? I am acquainted with PowerShell scripting, but how to get around this silly prompt *and* have it save the data is beyond me. Anything that cancels the capture means I lose the data.

PS: the issue is not about speed ("performance") as such, it's much more about performing *at all*, because Defender keeps failing our builds. But I get why they would want ETW or trace logging details.

Comment: If by "build" you mean a build of Windows, I have not had a Windows build fail because of Defender. It is well designed and built to work properly in Windows.  I suggest looking at your build to see if it is doing something non-compliant.

Comment: Also, it you are using a third party AV, make sure (test) that is works in harmony with Windows Defender.  I stopped and my customers stopped using third party AV (Symantec Corporate in our case) at build 18xx of Windows 10. Just Defender after that.

Comment: @John I mean a build of software my company offers. It's an MSBuild-based build and involves Visual Studio 2022. I don't know what you could possibly mean by "build of Windows". I'm not working at Microsoft. There's no third-party AV involved either. And please don't tell me about "well designed". Ever since Microsoft has aggressively pushed performance demands through MVI, they themselves have become sloppy with how Defender does stuff. Formally it probably fulfills their own requirements. But an AV with an FSFD has other ways than exclusively holding a file. I developed such stuff.

Comment: @0xC0000022L... I'm not sure about `Get-MpPerformanceReport -Path <recording.etl>` but this https://i.imgur.com/kFjASw7.png, it makes network level ETW and later optionally converted to cap via Message Analyzer export easy. Sounds like you got the command and data results as expected so no issue there, you just want to automate some manual clicks or key presses when something prompts, etc. Have you run `Get-Help New-MpPerformanceRecording -Full` just to ensure nothing shows there a way to trigger a stop otherwise. I use better than MS Defender in my main corp case with EDR, etc.

Comment: @0xC0000022L When you have detailed information about trusted files, like their hash, path, and digital signature, utilizing a specific allow list is more efficient. Explicitly allow trusted files through endpoint protection, **using multiple validation rules**, rather than troubleshooting performance issues. This approach ensures only necessary machines receive explicit exceptions, avoiding unnecessary interference.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle do you consider Message Analyzer still viable? Where would I get a copy that I can trust? IIRC Microsoft abandoned it in 2017 or so and isn't offering downloads for it anymore. I ran `Get-Help New-MpPerformanceRecording` without `-Full`. Thanks for pointing that out! As to your last comment, I have no influence on the exclusions (well, technically I do, but it would sidestep corporate rules). Again, the issue isn't performance as in speed, the issue is that Defender breaks builds by hogging access to files. Only wait+retry currently _somewhat_ helps.

Comment: I have an MSI for it and for running quick network traffic scans and then using it to export to a Wireshark compatible files, it is much easier than installing all the needed Wireshark component otherwise on a server or a client (or both) to run a network trace. If it works and makes something easier, then I consider it viable even thought it's an intermediary steps to use Wireshark for looking at packets.  I'm not able to get `New-MpPerformanceRecord` cmdlet to help more. Is it a license M365 E5 only tool if you use Defender?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are doing builds either. I like making a lot of the initial configs in workstations (not servers) builds get things done at startup. Usually the endpoint security in my case is in unmanaged mode and everything works post image push, then sysprep boot up, etc. Wonder if your sequence of actions for "build" could be changed to optimize. Otherwise, stuck with tools to capture causing issues could be challenging.

Comment: Here you go, scan with virustotal and then your own security software before you run, this seems to be a legit one though. I will now download it and scan it myself too: https://github.com/riverar/messageanalyzer-archive/tree/master/releases/1.4... It is safe per the scan I completed: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9bc60aa8f823b9dd27943a78f64fd74b676b13d45eb546801bc487f565b7c1ea

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle can't tell you anything about the license attached to it (simply because I don't know), but it's something a corporation with over >10,000 staff would book from MS. I know they use InTune. That's about it, and they don't let on that much. My current hope is that starting next year we will get some build agents that we can manage to the extent that we can control exclusions during builds. I am not opposed to run on-demand scans on the result (in fact this would be beneficial, as we have had false positives in the past due to .exe "protectors" being used).

Comment: I've never been a limited admin in my IT career like that but experience providing support for thousands of machines both workstation and server, and across multiple domains. For me and some issue like this, I would personally look into a temporary disablement of the protections/processes in place for build out configuration, and then make disabling and then enabling that as part of the process. If you are local admin on the machine, you should be able to work that out. Then it's a non-issue. I'm not sure who sees what with your config specifics or your rules either though.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle the thing is that the IT dept wants exactly that info. While I know how to sidestep Defender, that's not going to cut it. Because by sidestepping it, I'd end up getting an empty ETL. But thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @0xC0000022L What ever came solution wise for all of this? Anything help, figure out a workaround to suppress during build phase, etc. Curious where you got with this issue and how you're handling it now if any different.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly**, I'll incorporate and cite some key elements from the [Description: New-MpPerformanceRecording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/tune-performance-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide#description-new-mpperformancerecording) post, which could offer valuable insights into vendor support and its implications, at the very least.

> This `New-MpPerformanceRecording` cmdlet provides an insight into
> problematic files that could cause a degradation in the performance of
> Microsoft Defender Antivirus. **This tool is provided "AS IS"**, and
> is not intended to provide suggestions on exclusions. Exclusions can
> reduce the level of protection on your endpoints. Exclusions, if any,
> should be defined with caution.
>
> For more information on the performance analyzer, see [Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer) docs.

**Additionally**, I've identified a potential workaround idea per what's outlined in [Example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/tune-performance-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide#example-2-collect-a-performance-recording-for-remote-powershell-session) of the Microsoft post's section which I'll cite and reference key points below for clarity first.

> **Example 2:** **Collect a performance recording for remote PowerShell session**
>
> ```
> $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server02 -Credential Domain01\User01 
> New-MpPerformanceRecording -RecordTo C:\LocalPathOnServer02\trace.etl -Session $s
> ```
>
> The above command collects a performance recording on `Server02` (as
> specified by argument `$s` of parameter Session) and saves it to the
> specified path: `C:\LocalPathOnServer02\trace.etl` on `Server02`.
>
> **Parameters: `New-MpPerformanceRecording`**
>
> **`-RecordTo`**
>
> Specifies the location in which to save the Microsoft Defender
> Antimalware performance recording.
>
> **`-Session`**
>
> Specifies the PSSession object in which to create and save the
> Microsoft Defender Antivirus performance recording. **When you use this
> parameter the `RecordTo` parameter refers to the local path on the
> remote machine**. Available with Defender platform version 4.18.2201.10

## Potential Workaround

Create a remote interactive session with `New-PSSession` and store it in a variable (e.g. `$s`). Then, use the variable with the [`-Session`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/tune-performance-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide#-session) parameter of `New-MpPerformanceRecording`

Once sufficient time has passed to collect necessary events, use [`Remove-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession?view=powershell-7.4) along with the respective variable (e.g. `Remove-PSSession $s`)  to end the remote session and halt the session capture operations.

### PowerShell Example 1

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server02 -Credential Domain01\User01
New-MpPerformanceRecording -RecordTo C:\LocalPathOnServer02\trace.etl -Session $s

## After enough time has passed, run this command or schedule it
Remove-PSSession $s
```

### PowerShell Example 2

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server02 -Credential Domain01\User01

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    New-MpPerformanceRecording -RecordTo C:\LocalPathOnServer02\trace.etl
}

## After enough time has passed, run this command or schedule it
Remove-PSSession $s
```

Comment: @0xC0000022L Here are some things that seem to make sense logically to me after reading over the MS post another time and spotting the remote access potentials to help. It will be worth testing the ETL files afterwards if this works to ensure they are not corrupt. I'm not able to run these commands to test for 100% confidence, but since you are needing help, I decided to post just in case. Worse case, you tell me this is trash and I delete the post. Otherwise, it is worth the potential from my side to help you even if a workaround for more automation flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
# Define the path for recording.etl
$etlPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Recording.etl"

# Start the performance recording
New-MpPerformanceRecording -RecordTo $etlPath

# Sleep to allow time for the recording to capture data (adjust as needed)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

# Stop the performance recording
Stop-MpPerformanceRecording
```